# Is it true that $\mathrm{codim}(Z \cap Y, Y) \leq\mathrm{codim}(Z,X)$ for closed subsets $Z,Y$ of a scheme $X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

This might be a standard thing but I'm not so sure.

> Say $X$ is an irreducible affine scheme, $Y$ is an irreducible closed subset of $X$, and $Z$ a closed subset of $X$. If $Z \cap Y \neq \emptyset$ is it true that
>   $$\mathrm{codim}(Z \cap Y, Y) \leq \mathrm{codim}(Z,X),$$
>   where on the left we have the codimension of $Z \cap Y$ in $Y$ and on the right we have the codimension of $Z$ in $X$?

I believe to have seen this in the context of Krull's intersection theorem but I don't see how this follows. I also do not want to assume that $X$ is noetherian.

Comment: What happens when $Y,Z$ are codimension one subvarieties which are disjoint?

Comment: Good point. I refined my question.

Comment: Just a remark that may be irrelevant: this is true if $Y$ is an open subset of $X$. But I don't immediately see how to generalize the argument for that to a closed subset that isn't necessarily open.

Comment: @Keenan: Yes, for Y open I've seen a tiny lemma in the stacks project, this is true. What I actually have is that Z is of codim 1 in X and want that it is of codim 1 in Y. I don't know if this makes things better (correct).

Comment: Take $xy-zw=0$ in 4-space as your $X$, $Y: x=z=0$ and $Z: y=w=0$. You get 2 on the left and 1 on the right.

Comment: Alright, thanks. What then did I get wrong from these notes: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/swb2.pdf. "Rephrased, the codimension of X ∩ Y in Y is at most the codimension of X in the ambient space." (Here, X is my Z and the ambient space is my X). Does this only work for Z a hypersurface? Is the inequality the other way around?

Comment: Unlikely that Hochster makes such mistakes. I am sure he is right and you are not reading him carefully, in particular, his assumptions.

Comment: @Moha: Yes, I probably missed an assumption. Anyways, in Hartshorne Prop 7.1 there is this "affine dimension theorem": $Y,Z$ varieties in $\mathbb{A}^n$ of dimension $r,s$. Then every irreducible component of $Y \cap Z$ has dimension $\geq r+s-n$. Now, suppose $Z$ is of codimension one, i.e., $dim(Z) = n-1$. Then by the theorem $dim(Y \cap Z) \geq r+n-1-n = r-1$, so either $Y \cap Z = Y$ or $Y \cap Z$ is of codimension one in $Y$.  Where's my mistake? What about $Y \cap Z = \emptyset$?

Comment: It should say if not empty. Then for affine spaces it is correct.

Comment: But then I don't understand your counterexample (which is correct!): $Y \cap Z$ is of codimension 2 in $Y$, not 1 what I get from the formula. I make some mistake here.

Comment: The difference is probably that $\mathbf{A}^n$ is smooth.